Is dropping a weapon "free" in terms of action cost?
Under the 2014 rules, it was ruled that dropping a weapon you were holding didn't require any action, not even your 1/turn free object interaction, even though RAW had no specific rules on it.
Now, with the 2024 rules: Is dropping a weapon totally "free" in terms of action cost?
Can you still drop weapons from both hands, and draw a new one or pick up one you dropped,
and still take an action and bonus action?

Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

The rules aren't explicit
Dropping a weapon is only mentioned under the rules for attacking, as one of the ways you can unequip a weapon before or after an attack. So dropping a weapon can be done "for free" if you're making an attack.
The other relevant rule is the rule for object interactions. In combat, you get one object interaction for free and must take the Utilize action to interact with a second one. So what constitutes an interaction? The rules never specify it. They give a couple examples, like closing a door, but it's really left up to the DM to decide.
I would personally rule that dropping something requires absolutely no effort and would not require an object interaction, but that's just my opinion. The rules can't possibly list all possible object interactions so it's left up to the DM.

Technically, It’s Still Free
Dropping a weapon counts as unequipping it in the context of an Attack action, but this context is limited to that action:

Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You can do so either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.

The inclusion of "dropping" here is part of the definition of "unequipping" in this special context. However, there is almost never a reason to drop something instead of stowing it for free as part of the Attack action, because dropping a weapon risks someone else picking it up. Thus, the Attack action rules provide additional action economy, demonstrating how exceptions supersede general rules:

When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.

It would be imbalanced and illogical to treat dropping a weapon as equivalent to actions like opening a door, pulling a lever, or sheathing a weapon. The latter actions demand time, attention, and coordination, while dropping something requires no effort, a fact corroborated by the rules for falling Unconscious:

You have the Incapacitated and Prone conditions, and you drop whatever you’re holding.

This supports the argument that dropping an item is effortless and should not constitute a Time-Limited Object Interaction.1 Otherwise, dropping a weapon would require a different action economy than any other object, even though no rules define the cost of dropping an object, and dropping a weapon is never described as a Time-Limited Object Interaction.
As another user pointed out, dropping a weapon should require no more time or effort than removing one hand from a Versatile:

A Versatile weapon can be used with one or two hands.

or Two-Handed weapon:

A Two-Handed weapon requires two hands when you attack with it.

The RAW (Rules as Written) do not assign a cost for switching between one-handed and two-handed use of a Versatile weapon or for holding a Two-Handed weapon in one hand. The 2014 PHB originally described the Two-Handed property as:

Two-Handed. This weapon requires two hands to use.

(cited here). This was clarified in the errata:

Two-Handed (p. 147). This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.

The 2024 rules now explicitly state:

...when you attack with it.

This implies that holding a Two-Handed weapon in one hand is valid. Since no cost is defined for switching between hands or grips, it is eminently reasonable to infer that these actions are free.
By tying the unequipping rule specifically to the Attack action, the game avoids unnecessary complications in action economy while maintaining consistency. Treating dropping a weapon as anything other than free would create conceptual absurdities and undermine balance, forcing players to spend disproportionate resources on a fundamentally effortless act. This design choice ensures mechanics remain intuitive and balanced while preserving the intended fluidity and strategic depth of the game.

Addendum:
This question was updated to address dual-wielding. The assumption that dropping a weapon requires expenditure of the free environmental Interaction implies that a character cannot drop two weapons and take an action (other than Attack) in the same turn. This interpretation becomes even more problematic when considering the Dual Wielder feat, which allows stowing two weapons simultaneously but does not explicitly address "unequipping." Such a restriction would be inconsistent and absurd.

1: The designers assumed this in 2015: ...letting go of something requires no appreciable effort. But picking it up does.

I know you asked a nearly identical-in-title question to this one relating specifically to items and not weapons. The last two paragraphs of your answer here feel like they're intended for that other question as you consistently reference things that aren't weapons.

With your second link, can you provide a relevant quote from it to support the answer to mitigate link rot?

good call. will revise

I edited the question to clarify what I think it was asking, whether Crawford's 2015 tweet that dropping an object you're holding should be totally free, not even your 1/turn free object interaction, so you can also pick something up and still have your action and bonus.  You're arguing that if a player wants to drop a weapon and draw a new one, they can say they're dropping their weapon outside of the attack action (because you agree with Crawford's 2015 tweet that it takes no effort at all), and using their free equip/unequip to draw the new one?

So you'd be arguing that the mention of "dropping" in the equip/unequip paragraph doesn't need to be there, and using that rule to drop a weapon is sub-optimal because you can do it totally free instead?  In other words, that the rules are imperfect and are basically suggesting a worse way of dropping things you're holding.

@PeterCordes, I'm suggesting that the inclusion of "dropping" in that clause is there to define what constitutes "unequipping" a weapon. Otherwise, yes, some part of that rule is sub-optimal, because there is no need to drop a weapon when you can stow it for "free" as part of the attack.

@nonymous Attack Action: "You can either equip or unequip one weapon [...] Unequipping a weapon includes dropping it". RAW, unequipping/dropping a weapon requires effort, because the rule included in the Attack Action limits the number of unequips/drops you can do. By default (no feats, no Extra Attacks), you cannot unequip/drop two or more weapons when taking the Attack Action. Only one. The rules make it clear that unequiping a weapon isn't free in terms of cost. And if it's not free during the Attack Action, why would it be when using the Time-Limited Object Interactions rule?

@Tarod, No. "You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action." It is decidedly free as part of the attack. Those rules are specific to the attack action, and they make it clear that an attacker doesn't need to worry about unnecessary action economy. By "default" you also cannot attack with two weapons as part of the attack action (Vex mastery not being default); that's why.

If you take the Attack Action and have, for example, a two-handed weapon in your hand (equipped) and a different weapon in a sheath (unequipped), you cannot drop your weapon AND equip/draw the weapon from the sheath during the same Action. Why? Because dropping a weapon isn't free. It’s time-consuming according to the rules. If it were as you're saying, why would the rule even mention "drop"? (BTW, I don’t understand the mention of Vex in relation to using two weapons.)

Not Vex, sorry, Nick

The Two-handed property is irrelevant to the discussion, especially because such a weapon can be held (equipped) in one hand; only, it cannot be wielded in an attack unless held with two hands. Regardless, the logic only pertains to the special, exceptional context of attacking. The special free weapon interaction during the attack adds additional action economy, it doesn't define limits on actions in general.

If dropping a weapon isn't free, then why does it happen when you're unconscious?

Exactly for the same reason. Specific beats general, and since dropping isn't free, the Unconscious Condition gives you a specific rule: drop whatever you’'e holding.

@Tarod, why would the unconscious condition give a specific rule to drop whatever you’re holding if it cost time and attention ? If you’re  willing to concede that specific beats general in that case, then why not in the Attack rules? From my perspective, it looks like grasping at straws to defend a false conviction.  It seems pretty clear at this point that your position is the least popular among the community, anyway. I’d encourage you to be a bit more open-minded about the possibility that you’re mistaken.

“removing one hand from a two-handed weapon […] of course has no cost,” doesn’t sit right with me—you can’t just say “of course” the rules work a certain way, you have to back it up. I’m not very familiar with any rules around that in 5e, but in 3.x (and Paizo’s spin-off, Pathfinder) this point has been argued pretty fervently, so I don’t think it’s fair to just assume.

Ok, @KRyan, I can cite versatile weapons more carefully, for you.

@nonymous Thank you, that looks quite appropriate. I agree it is “eminently reasonable,” but it’s only fair to our readers to let them have the facts and decide that for themselves.

You’re right, of course.

Dropping is a weapon interaction
According to the PHB 2024 (p. 361), dropping a Weapon counts as an item interaction in the same way as drawing, sheathing or stowing a weapon does, and it requires the same cost in terms of both effort and time (emphasis mine):

Attack [Action]
Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one
weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You do so
either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an
attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon
includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a
weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.

If dropping a weapon were completely free, it wouldn't have been included on the list. The same applies to picking a weapon up from the ground or the other options you have: they're not free.
Additionally, by default, there is available a free interaction per turn involving objects (a Weapon is an object; see below). These are the rules (emphasis mine):
PHB, p. 20:

What Is an Object?
For the purpose of the rules, an object is a
discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table,
chair, or stone. It isn’t a building or a vehicle, which are composed
of many objects.
Time-Limited Object Interactions
When time is short, such as in
combat, interactions with objects are limited: one free interaction
per turn. That interaction must occur during a creature’s movement or
action. Any additional interactions require the Utilize action, as
explained in “Combat” later in this chapter.

PHB, p. 24:

Your Turn
Interacting with Things. You can interact with one
object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move
or action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you
stride toward a foe.
If you want to interact with a second object, you need to take the
Utilize action. Some magic items and other special objects always
require an action to use, as stated in their descriptions.

Finally, a Weapon is an Object. From the Glossary:

Weapon
A weapon is an object that is in the Simple or Martial weapon
category. See also chapter 6 (“Weapons”).

Conclusions
RAW, a sword, or any other weapon, is an object, and interactions with objects are limited to one free interaction per turn. That interaction must occur during a creature's movement or action.
Using the mentioned rules, here are some examples:

You could unequip/drop a weapon using your Free Interaction, then take the Attack Action, draw a new weapon, and attack with it.
If your Free Interaction isn't available, you could take the Attack Action, and unequip/drop your weapon, but you wouldn't be able to draw a new one.
If you're not using the Attack Action, you could not unequip/drop a weapon and equip it again in the same turn unless you take the Utilize Action.

Example in the Player's Handbook
There is also an example on the PHB, p. 31, which is possible thanks to the use of the Time-Limited Object Interactions rule, in addition to the Equipping & Unequipping Weapons rule. Note that "drop" is mentioned twice on purpose.

Russell: I drop my sword and pull out my warhammer [...]


Vulnerability. An attack that deals bludgeoning damage is deadly to skeletons. Shreeve knows this from past experience, which is why she drops her sword and switches to a Bludgeoning weapon. [...]


Could you provide some insight into the leap in logic from the Attack action rules to dropping a weapon in general, especially how it qualifies as an item interaction?

I added more rules about objects, highlighting the relevant parts.

Agreed that a Weapon is always an Object and not vice versa. However, this still neglects to demonstrate how the special/exceptional Attack rules pertain to general object interactions. Does that make sense? My claim is that the Attack action gives additional action economy on top of regular object interaction. The "burder of proof" is to show that it doesn't.

"My claim is that the Attack action gives additional action economy on top of regular object interaction". This is true. Equipping and Unequipping Weapons is intended to be in addition to the Time-Limited Object Interaction. However, a Weapon is an Object, just as an Object can be a Weapon. Therefore, dropping an object requires using your free interaction per turn.

Can't say I agree, for 2 reasons: 1) The rules allow for you to draw a weapon + attack (action) and then walk over and open a door (Interaction); 2) Dropping something is never defined as interacting with it.

So you still also get one object-interaction separate from the one that comes with the attack action, interesting.  So you could stow one weapon that way and draw another as part of an attack?  I guess that's a separate question, whether your one free object interaction can be with a weapon you were already holding.

Shields and armor are also objects, and you're constantly interacting with them during a fight, but that obviously doesn't take up your object interaction. So, clearly we can infer that not everything that can be described as an "interaction" with an object is an Object Interaction. The given examples suggest it must meet a threshold of effort, and none of your sources suggest that merely "dropping" something meets that threshold. (If anything, you're ceasing your interaction with it)
